# How can i segment clients on granular level using python and ML?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, cluster-analysis

#### Novice alert

I have been learning ML in python for the last few months and have had some great results. Currently, however, I am stuck with a project and require the guidance of someone with more experience (Google can only take you so far it appears  ).

#### What I am trying to achieve

I have a dummy data set full of clients and their transactions. I want to cluster or segment them into much smaller 'tribes' based on their demographic data, spending score and shopping behaviour. For example, one 'tribes' description could be something this granular : (men, aged 35 who primarily purchase music-based products on a Saturday afternoon within the first half of each month and have a high spending score)
I want to find the sweet spot between granular segmentation and general segmentation eg: segmentation by income and spending score.

#### What I have tried

Firstly, I have allocated an int value representing the frequency of each categorical occurrence across each client's transactions. For example :

```
Client | Home  | Movies | Games 
    1      3        1       0
```

This indicates that Client 1 has purchased Home related items 3 times, Movie related items 1 time and they have never purchased any item in the Games category.

I have done the same for  Days (i.e Sunday - Saturday), Week number (i.e 1-5 the week number in any given month), Hour (i.e hour_one - hour_twenty_four).

This approach allows me to create a clean vector of purely numerical data.

This is an example of my raw input data in JSON format (before processing):

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "customer_id": 1,
        "age": 47,
        "gender": "Female",
        "first_name": "Lea",
        "last_name": "Calafato",
        "email": "lcalafato0@cafepress.com",
        "phone_number": "612-170-5956",
        "income_k": 24,
        "location": "Nottingham",
        "sign_up_date": "2/16/2019",
        "transactions": [
            {
                "customer_id": "1",
                "product_id": 42,
                "product_cat": "Home",
                "price": 106.92,
                "time": "8:15 PM",
                "date": "04/15/2019",
                "day": "Monday",
                "week_num": 3
            },
            {
                "customer_id": "1",
                "product_id": 30,
                "product_cat": "Movies",
                "price": 26.63,
                "time": "10:12 AM",
                "date": "09/17/2019",
                "day": "Tuesday",
                "week_num": 4
            }
        ],
        "number_of_purchases": 2,
        "last_purchase": "09/17/2019",
        "total_spent": 133.55
    }
]
```

This is my dataframe after being processed and standardized :

```
age                  750 non-null int64
income_k             750 non-null int64
spending_score       750 non-null int64
gender__Female       750 non-null uint8
gender__Male         750 non-null uint8
Home                 750 non-null float64
Movies               750 non-null float64
Games                750 non-null float64
Grocery              750 non-null float64
Music                750 non-null float64
Health               750 non-null float64
Beauty               750 non-null float64
Sports               750 non-null float64
Toys                 750 non-null float64
Garden               750 non-null float64
Computers            750 non-null float64
Clothing             750 non-null float64
Books                750 non-null float64
Outdoors             750 non-null float64
Industrial           750 non-null float64
Kids                 750 non-null float64
Tools                750 non-null float64
Automotive           750 non-null float64
Electronics          750 non-null float64
Jewelery             750 non-null float64
Baby                 750 non-null float64
Shoes                750 non-null float64
week_one             750 non-null float64
week_two             750 non-null float64
week_three           750 non-null float64
week_four            750 non-null float64
week_five            750 non-null float64
Sunday               750 non-null float64
Monday               750 non-null float64
Tuesday              750 non-null float64
Wednesday            750 non-null float64
Thursday             750 non-null float64
Friday               750 non-null float64
Saturday             750 non-null float64
hour_one             750 non-null float64
hour_two             750 non-null float64
hour_three           750 non-null float64
hour_four            750 non-null float64
hour_five            750 non-null float64
hour_six             750 non-null float64
hour_seven           750 non-null float64
hour_eight           750 non-null float64
hour_nine            750 non-null float64
hour_ten             750 non-null float64
hour_eleven          750 non-null float64
hour_twelve          750 non-null float64
hour_thirteen        750 non-null float64
hour_fourteen        750 non-null float64
hour_fithteen        750 non-null float64
hour_sixteen         750 non-null float64
hour_seventeen       750 non-null float64
hour_eighteen        750 non-null float64
hour_nineteen        750 non-null float64
hour_twenty          750 non-null float64
hour_twenty_one      750 non-null float64
hour_twenty_two      750 non-null float64
hour_twenty_three    750 non-null float64
hour_twenty_four     750 non-null float64*
```

I have run this data through both k-means and DBSCAN algorithms to no avail. k-means gives me 4 clusters which are far too general for my requirements and DBSCAN gives me zero clusters with each data point being treated as noise.

My apologies if anything is unclear, please feel free to ask me to clarify anything. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We're missing the most important item from your problem description: what defines a "sweet spot"?  Is it some measure of cluster distance, or cluster size, or something derived from an understanding of each column's empirical qualities?  Unless it's a specific programming problem, you should not only refine your problem, but also move the posting to an appropriate group.  [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.

Comment: @Prune noted. In future, I will look for a more appropriate forum. As far as 'the sweet spot' i am simply appealing to the knowledge of someone with more experience who may have that answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen if your data is not scaled.
See a generic example here over the Iris data set:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from  sklearn.cluster import KMeans

iris = seaborn.load_dataset('iris')
scaling = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1)).fit(iris.iloc[:,:-1])
iris_scale = pd.DataFrame(scaling.transform(iris.iloc[:,:-1]),columns=iris.iloc[:,:-1].columns)
km = KMeans(n_clusters=3, random_state=1)
km.fit(iris_scale)
y_kmeans = pd.DataFrame({'cluster': km.predict(iris_scale), 'real':iris['species'], 'stam':1})
y_kmeans.pivot_table(index=['real'],columns=['cluster'], aggfunc='count')
```

This is the result you should get:

```
cluster        0     1     2
real                        
setosa       NaN  50.0   NaN
versicolor  47.0   NaN   3.0
virginica   14.0   NaN  36.0
```

Meaning that k-means clustered all of the 'setosa' species as cluster 1, even without knowing it was the same species.
Make sure your data is scaled (normalized).

Comment: I will give this a try. Thanks

Comment: `My data after being normalized :`

Comment: `         age  income_k  spending_score  gender__Female  gender__Male      Home    Movies  ...
0  0.889170  0.454044        0.000000        0.018919      0.000000  0.018919  0.018919  ...
1  0.209039  0.596147        0.758733        0.000000      0.007742  0.007742  0.007742  ...
2  0.492814  0.739221        0.197126        0.000000      0.024641  0.000000  0.049281  ...
3  0.438854  0.894586        0.000000        0.000000      0.016879  0.000000  0.000000  ...
4  0.280203  0.446249        0.809475        0.010378      0.000000  0.010378  0.031134  ... `

Comment: I still have the same issue as before. The clustering is too general.

Answer (score 0):

K-means will give you 4 clusters if you use k=4. If you want more costs, increase k...

Similarly, DBSCAN had a that need to set right to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Sure, however, I used the elbow method prior to running the data through a k-means clustering algorithm. As per online recommendation, it's good practise to set k to the point in which the data changes angle significantly.. or not??

Comment: The elbow method is crap for real data. It only works on toy examples. If you want more clusters, use a larger k. Although I wouldn't be surprised if k-means does not produce convincing results - it is very sensitive to good data preparation. Given your list of attributes I doubt *any* method will produce anything meaningful from this mess.

Comment: @Anoy-Mousse can you suggest a better list of attributes given my data set, telling me its a mess isn't very helpful. Also, why is the elbow method 'crap' for real data? Is there an alternative method for determining the optimal number of clusters?

Comment: Yes, there are two dozen better methods, easily findable in literature. But they all assume that your data is suitable for k-means; it requires *continuous* variables, but your attributes mostly seem to be binary. But other methoda will have similar problems: they rely on *you* defining a distance measurement such that related (for *your* problem!) records are more similar than different records.

Comment: So until *you* can mathematically define what a "good" cluster on such data would be (I certainly cannot see what would be good), I doubt you can get an algorithm to produce "good" results.